# How to ssh and run Smash CLP command by script?

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to write the script to ssh to server (bios interface) and run command as Smash CLP.

I try some command like:
ssh -t accout@remote_server 'command',
but it doesn't recognize 'command' as command for Smash CLP.

Comment: What `command` are you running exactly? My understanding is that you need to start with `connect clp`, right?

Answer (score 2):

Try to write your command in a file on your machine (say `command.clp`) and run

```
  ssh accout@remote_server 'connect clp' < command.clp
```

As an alternative, you can start your `command.clp` file with `connect clp` line followed by Smash CLP commands. In this case all you need to run is

```
  ssh accout@remote_server < command.clp
```

Comment: Thank Dmitry. However when access bios interface by ssh, I cannot create any file there.

Comment: So I figured, that's why I suggest to create a command file on *your machine* (not the server) and use it as input of your SSH session.